# get Phone Number from Facebook

Tags: swift, facebook, phone-number

I am new in swift. Can anyone tell me how to get phone number field from facebook.

Here button is pressed :

```
@IBAction func fbButtonAct(_ sender: Any) {
        view.endEditing(true)

        let fbLogin : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        let loadingOverlay = loadingOnScreen(self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(loadingOverlay)

        fbLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, err) in
            if(err != nil){
                print("custom fb login failed",err)
                loadingOverlay.removeFromSuperview()
                return
            }
            if (result?.isCancelled)!{
                loadingOverlay.removeFromSuperview()
                return
            }
            self.dataGettingFromFB(fbLogin, loadingOverlay: loadingOverlay)
            print(result?.token.tokenString)

        }
    }


func dataGettingFromFB(_ fbLogin:FBSDKLoginManager, loadingOverlay: UIView){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields":"id, email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), gender, phone"]).start { (connection, result, err) in

            if (err != nil){
                print("failed to start graph request:",err)
                loadingOverlay.removeFromSuperview()
                return
            }

            let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary

            var email : String? = fbDetails["email"] as? String
            if(email == nil){
                email = ""
            }

            let firstName = fbDetails["first_name"] as! String
            let id = fbDetails["id"] as! String
            let lastName = fbDetails["last_name"] as! String

            fbLogin.logOut()
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no way to get the phone number

Comment: just asking how did uber pick up phone number by facebook login

Comment: uber is a smartphone app. they get the phone number with the smartphone permissions, not with facebook login.

Comment: k thankyou for your time and answers

Answer (score -1):

Try this : put the public_profile to read permission

fbLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email","public_profile"], from: self)

Comment: not working
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            "fbtrace_id" = "D2cL/IolPWC";
            message = "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (phone) on node type (User)";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
},

Comment: , com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (phone) on node type (User), com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0})

Comment: @Gaurav add user_friends permission also

Comment: stilll not working same error

Comment: @Gaurav No, there is no way to get the phone number. There is no permission, and there is no data field for this in the API.

Comment: just asking how did uber pick up phone number by facebook login

Comment: same error here trying to access phone number and getting same error.